# Error: 'str' object is not callable python

Tags: python

I have been stuck dealing with an error in python and have been searching for a while to fix it but to no avail.

Here is the error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wood\Desktop\Software design\Program 4\program3_4QuinnWood.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\wood\Desktop\Software design\Program 4\program3_4QuinnWood.py", line 23, in main
    displayOutput(letterCount,middleCharacter,spaceAmount,aReplace)
  File "C:\Users\wood\Desktop\Software design\Program 4\program3_4QuinnWood.py", line 56, in displayOutput
    print('Number of letters:'(letterCount))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is the code I have written so far.

```
def main():

    while True:
        sentence= userInput()
        letterCount= characterCount(sentence)
        middleCharacter= middleLetter(sentence)
        spaceAmount= spaceCount(sentence)
        aReplace= letterReplace(sentence)
        displayOutput(letterCount,middleCharacter,spaceAmount,aReplace)


def userInput():
    sentence = str(input('Enter a sentence at least 10 letters long, or type STOP to quit:')) 
    if sentence == 'STOP':
        quit()
    return sentence

def characterCount(sentence):
    letterCount = len(sentence) - sentence.count(' ')
    if letterCount < 10:

        print('Sorry that is less than 10 letters')


def middleLetter(sentence):
    sentence = len(sentence)/2
    middleCharacter = [sentence +1]


def spaceCount(sentence):
    spaceAmount = sentence.count(' ')



def letterReplace(sentence):
    aReplace= sentence.replace("a", "&")



def displayOutput(letterCount,middleCharacter,spaceAmount,aReplace):
    print('Number of letters:'(letterCount))
    print('Middle letter:'(middleCharacter))
    print('Spaces counted:'(spaceAmount))
    print('Sentence with letter replaced:'(aReplace))

main()
```

The solution is probably something simple that I am overlooking but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363786/object-of-type-function-has-no-len-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

The error states `str object not callable` which meant you were treating strings like functions or anything which is callable `()` in your code.

The issue is in the print statements in `displayOutput()` function

Corrected code

```
def displayOutput(letterCount,middleCharacter,spaceAmount,aReplace):
    print('Number of letters:',letterCount)
    print('Middle letter:',middleCharacter)
    print('Spaces counted:',spaceAmount)
    print('Sentence with letter replaced:',aReplace)

main()
```